# Identify the missing value in a table

Tags: data-mining, data, data-cleaning

How to compute the missing values x in the below table. which **formula** can be used to obtain the values of x. The values in the last row and last column are the sums of the rows and columns. What is the simplest method to find the missing values?

[image]

Comment: You mention "identify"... "compute"... "formula"... are you asking how to **impute** the "missing" values in X?

Comment: If you are asking impute, it depends on your use case and data. You can use as simple as that or you can use something like KNNImputer.